# How to refresh git repository name in git for windows?

Tags: git, github

I have renamed my git repository using web interface.
Now the changed name is not reflecting in my windows git tool.

How can I refresh it without cloning repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cloned repo has no name, except maybe the name of its parent root folder.

You can rename that root folder (the one which included the `.git/` inside) at any time in order to reflect the name of the remote repo manage by your web interface.